# Django M2M / Many To Many Relationship to SELF in 1 Django Admin Inline

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I'm trying to set a Many To Many relationship on a model to itself.  I have read up on the whole Symmetrical=True/False settings.  I do want the symmetry between the self related models, aka, if the locale1 of model Locale is related to another Locale, locale2, then locale2 should have a reference to get locale1.  Below is how I have the models set up Locale and the Many To Many Model/Table RelatedLocale.

When viewing in Django Admin, locale1 will show the relation to locale2, but when looking at locale2, it does not show locale1.

I have to make 2 separate inlines to account for the **'core.RelatedLocale' has more than one ForeignKey to 'core.Locale'. You must specify a 'fk_name' attribute** error that is thrown because Django is confused by it pointing to itself.

Is there any way to make a m2m to self show in only 1 inline on both objects?

**Django 3.2.x**

**shell**

```
>>> locale1.related_locales.set([locale2])
>>> locale1.related_locales.all()
<QuerySet [<Locale: Locale object (<locale2>)>]>
>>> locale2.related_locales.all()
<QuerySet []>
```

**Models:**

```
class Locale(models.Model):
    """Locale to be used for everything on the Aspiria Campus"""
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ...
    related_locales = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self", through='RelatedLocale')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'locale'

class RelatedLocale(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    locale = models.ForeignKey(
        Locale, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='locale_id')
    related_locale = models.ForeignKey(
        Locale, related_name="related_locale", on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='related_locale_id')
    is_parent = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "related_locale"

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s related" % self.locale.name
```